# Debian Stretch: error upgrading watchdog

Tags: debian, sysvinit

When upgrading the `watchdog` package, `apt-get upgrade` does not complete.

If fails with the following error:

```
watchdog /run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  
Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
```

I am running sysVinit, however due to Debian changes, I am running udev, and the daemon `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd` is running.

Why this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the relevant code at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/watchdog.postinst`, it shows it checks for the presence of the MAKEDEV script.

```
 if [ -x "`which MAKEDEV`" ]; then
        ...
        # do we have to create the temperature device?
        if [ ! -c /dev/temperature ]
        then
            (cd /dev; MAKEDEV misc || true)
        fi
```

The solution to be able to finish the upgrade of the `watchdog` package is to delete the `makedev` package, as it is redundant with `udev`.

```
dpkg --purge makedev
```

After deleting the `makedev`, running `at-get upgrade` seems to be able to finish.

Comment: It's weird that you don't have a `/dev/watchdog` device (populated by `udev`)...

Comment: @StephenKitt I do not have a `/dev/temperature`, let me change the example...

Comment: Ah yes, that makes more sense! Still, this doesn't explain the `apt-get upgrade` failure — [`MAKEDEV` exits with 0 in this case](http://git.gag.com/?p=debian/makedev;a=blob;f=MAKEDEV;h=e0d78a2e60e498a10c3631446a35d0c5231c477b;hb=HEAD#l60) to avoid breaking `postinst` scripts (and has done since March 2005).

Comment: I will try to setup a VM tomorrow to test this out again.

Comment: This could be an instance of [#772826](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=772826).

Comment: (In any case, `MAKEDEV` errors are ignored by the `|| true`.)